# Python- How To Get Output Of Sudo Command Using Popen

Tags: python, linux, macos, sudo

`sudo` command validates the password of the user against the user name. I am writing a simple program which checks if the user's input is valid according to the `sudo` command. I am using the `-S` tag in order to pass an input externally, and i am using `Popen()` to run the script:

```
import getpass
import subprocess
import time

password = getpass.getpass()
proc = subprocess.Popen('sudo -k -S -l'.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate(password.encode())
print(f'This is the value of the output {output[0]}')
```

If the user inputs the wrong password in the `getpass.getpass()` I need to validate it against the actual user password. In this case, sudo should output `Sorry Please Try Again`. Could someone please let me know how I can read that error?

When I run this in the terminal:

```
➜  Desktop python3.8 test.py
Password: 
Sorry, try again.
This is the value of the output b''
```

Thanks, cheers and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The command gets stuck and nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) says:

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE.

So use

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', '-l'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

to allow writing a password with `communicate`, otherwise it just waits for you to enter it on the terminal (without a prompt since it's being captured).

Any error messages are available in the `output` variable, specifically `output[1]` which corresponds to stderr.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and now it is taking the input, however, how can i capture the "Sorry please try again" ?

Comment: You *have* captured it. It's in your `output` variable, but in `output[1]` while you just looked at `output[0]`

Comment: thanks so much, what would be a valid method now to confirm if the password is wrong ? the output when i write the wrong password is this ```[sudo] password for tejas: [sudo] password for tejas: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

Comment: You can set the environment variable `LC_ALL=C` to make sure the language is always the same and then e.g. match the substring `"incorrect password"`. Hopefully it's fairly stable over time. Not sure why you'd ever try to do this, but that's a different matter.